# How to keep the page without overlapping the entire page

Tags: css

if you open the below link  the content part is overlapped by id #a and #b
, my entire webpage is overlapped by those id's,if i change the  path absolute to relative the #a #b ,toggle script wont work. how to keep the toggle body height varies by text ,like text height equal to height of the toggle body.

http://jsfiddle.net/M6xJT/10/

Comment: let me see if I understand correctly, you want that the green div occupies the size of the text?

Comment: exactly, green and pink div's are overlapping my entire webpage , so i want to keep the pink and green div's height as size text height

Comment: jsfiddle.net/M6xJT/10 Open this link , the text "content here" is hidden under the toggle css code..

Comment: but "content here", should be inside in some div, right?

Comment: I don't have time to do a full answer right now, but here's a start: http://jsfiddle.net/M6xJT/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so you want this?

http://jsfiddle.net/M6xJT/12/

you have to remove the `bottom:0px;`

Comment: How to change the sidebar from left to right?thanks in advance

Comment: mmmm a quick solution is something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/M6xJT/14/

it has some bugs...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your content inside #B.  Unless I am missing something?  I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish.

```
<div id='B'>body<a href='javascript:' id='toggle' class='left'></a>
Content here
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M6xJT/10/ Open this link , the text "content here" is hidden under the toggle css code...

Comment: I see.  I just misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish.